# Model with normalized binary cross entropy loss does not converge

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm trying to implement normalized binary cross entropy for a classification task following this paper: [Normalized Loss Functions for Deep Learning with Noisy Labels](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.13554.pdf).
The math is as follows:
[image]

Here is my implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.utils import losses_utils

class NormalizedBinaryCrossentropy(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(
            self,
            from_logits=False,
            label_smoothing=0.0,
            axis=-1,
            reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE,
            name="normalized_binary_crossentropy",
            **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(
            reduction=reduction, name=name
        )
        self.from_logits = from_logits
        self._epsilon = tf.keras.backend.epsilon()

    def call(self, target, logits):
        if tf.is_tensor(logits) and tf.is_tensor(target):
            logits, target = losses_utils.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
                logits, target
            )
        logits = tf.convert_to_tensor(logits)
        target = tf.cast(target, logits.dtype)

        if self.from_logits:
            logits = tf.math.sigmoid(logits)

        logits = tf.clip_by_value(logits, self._epsilon, 1.0 - self._epsilon)

        numer = target * tf.math.log(logits) + (1 - target) * tf.math.log(1 - logits)
        denom = - (tf.math.log(logits) + tf.math.log(1 - logits))
        return - numer / denom

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"from_logits": self._from_logits})
        return config
```

I'm using this loss to train a binary classifier (CTR predictor), but loss of the model does not decrease and ROC-AUC remains at ~0.49-0.5. To verify the implementation of numerator, I tried training by removing the denominator and it's working fine.

```
# Example Usage

labels = np.array([[0], [1], [0], [0], [0]]).astype(np.int64)

logits = np.array([[-1.024], [2.506], [1.43], [0.004], [-2.0]]).astype(np.float64)

tf_nce = NormalizedBinaryCrossentropy(
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE,
    from_logits=True
)
tf_nce(labels, logits)

#<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 1), dtype=float64, numpy=
# array([[0.18737159],
#  [0.02945536],
#  [0.88459308],
#  [0.50144269],
#  [0.05631594]])>
```

I checked manually with some extremes and that loss doesn't hit nans or 0s.

Can anyone help me in debugging why the model is not able to converge on this loss? Is there something wrong with my understanding of the loss function or implementation?

Edit 1: Model architecture is a Multi-Gate Mixture-of-Experts with 6 tasks. All 6 tasks are binary classification and losses from all tasks are added together to get final loss.

Answer (score 1):

One thing which is mentioned in the paper as described above is that the Norm of the loss should be inclusively in between **`[0 ~ 1]`** but as your loss is violating this condition of **`Normalized Binary Cross Entropy`** and the other reason is you are dividing by the wrong denominator, you have to divide it by the Cross-Entropy of your `logits` for this take the `BinaryCrossEntropy()` of your `logits`. so, these can be the reasons that your function is not decreasing... I have made some changes to your code that satisfy this Norm Property...

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.utils import losses_utils

class NormalizedBinaryCrossentropy(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(
            self,
            from_logits=False,
            label_smoothing=0.0,
            axis=-1,
            reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE,
            name="normalized_binary_crossentropy",
            **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(
            reduction=reduction, name=name
        )
        self.from_logits = from_logits
        self._epsilon = tf.keras.backend.epsilon()

    def call(self, target, logits):
        if tf.is_tensor(logits) and tf.is_tensor(target):
            logits, target = losses_utils.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
                logits, target
            )
        logits = tf.convert_to_tensor(logits)
        target = tf.cast(target, logits.dtype)
        
        logits = tf.clip_by_value(logits, self._epsilon, 1.0 - self._epsilon)
        
        if self.from_logits:
            numer = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(target, logits,from_logits=True)[:,tf.newaxis]
            denom = -( tf.math.log(logits) + tf.math.log(1 - logits))
            return  numer * denom / tf.reduce_sum(denom)
        else:
            logits = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits)
            num = - tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(target, logits), axis=1)
            denom = -tf.math.reduce_sum(logits, axis=1)
            return num / denom

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"from_logits": self._from_logits})
        return config
```

I have updated the solution, there are two ways for computing the BCE if your logits are one-hot then set `from_logit=False` else set it `True`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this loss, but the loss seems to be increasing and roc-auc comes around `~.40`

Comment: I have edited the answer now kindly check it.

Comment: first read the intro...

Comment: I shall recommend you to take the mean loss, as I mentioned it in the comments.

Comment: Just tried the same loss as you shared, still doesn't work. and cross entropy loss > 1 (I got it in 100s just now). Running it on the example I shared, even that returns some values >1 and some negative.

Comment: There was a mistake in previous solution, try this one, one more thing also show your network summary atleast.

Comment: Still same issues. The model I'm using is Multi-gate mixture of expert with 6 binary classification tasks (added to the question as well). All losses from each task is added together to get the final loss.

Comment: We have to multiply the corresponding logits by their corresponding targets then we have to normalize it by the length of it. That's how it is implemented everywhere. Updated the solution.

Comment: We can't add clip_by_value before sigmoid/softmax to logits.. other wise all negative scores will be converted epsilon and larger ones 1-epsilon. Removing clip_by_value gives nan loss

Comment: I think it should be `if not self.from_logits` in if condition. otherwise `else` will apply log_softmax to already sigmoid values. Also multiplying target with logits will just zero out negatives from dataset.

Comment: I did it in hurry, fix it and then run it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid `log-Sigmoid` stability issues and try to implement the above model as a 2 class problem with `Softmax Binary cross entropy.`.

The NormalizedCrossEntropy is defined as:

```
class NormalizedCrossEntropy(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(NormalizedCrossEntropy, self).__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes

    def call(self, pred, labels):
        pred = tf.nn.log_softmax(pred, axis=1,)
        label_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels, self.num_classes)
        numer = -1 * tf.reduce_sum(label_one_hot * pred, axis=1) 
        denom = -1* tf.reduce_sum(pred, axis=1)
        nce = numer/ denom
        return nce
```

Example usage:

```
NormalizedCrossEntropy(num_classes=2)(np.array([[-1.024, 0.5], [0.1, 2.506], [1, .0], [0., 1.], [-0.89, -2.0]]), np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0]) )
#array([0.89725673, 0.03348167, 0.19259584, 0.80740416, 0.16958274]
```